# Can i manipulate typescript flow of my Vue.js app?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, frontend, vuejs3

I'd like to fully load my **main.ts** file **and after** it's completely loaded, initialize other files i am using as a *singleton*.

using `console.log()` I noticed my **singletonExample.ts** file is running before the **main.ts**, can i manipulate the flow to make **main.ts** *run before any other ts or js file*?

my example file contains **typescript classes**.

CODE EXAMPLE

**main.ts**

```
console.log('main');
```

**singletonExample.ts**

```
console.log("single");
```

//console result

```
single
main
```

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Please, post code instead of describing it. This looks XY like problem, consider explaining what you need to do instead of addressing potentially wrong way to make it work

Comment: Which part of having a main.ts and a random.ts file is so difficult to ask for code reproduction?
All i am asking doesn't revolve around code at all and is more an engineering question about javascript internal mechanisms.
If you really care about having "code" I am editing the question but imho doesn't really help.

Comment: You've seen your code and have an idea what you talk about. Others haven't seen it. The necessary amount of code is required by SO rules. You didn't show the imports, but it's pretty much clear at this point. The answer is that you can't do this with regular import statements, proceed from this fact. You need to move all the code that should be executed before singletonExample to separate module and import it before singletonExample. The alternative is to replace import statements with dynamic imports - require() or import(), but this will have more problems.

Comment: Again, this could be XY problem as you didn't explain why you need this, and the solution may vary depending on the case. It's unlikely that console.log alone would be a big deal

Answer (score 0):

Make your `singletonExample.ts` import `main.ts` as its first line

```
// singletonExample.ts
import 'main.ts'
```

Then `main.ts` will always be executed before `singletonExample.ts`